# HTML Table + Dropdown Button to redirect me to a servlet

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I am a newbie in html/css thing. I have this vertical table with a dropdown button at the bottom of it. What I want is, lets say, all the 3 options of the dropdown button to redirect me to a specific servlet. Say servlet "A". But each of these options have a different value. Depending on the value , the servlet will do something specific. How can I , though, get the output of that table, into that same servlet? THANKS IN ADVANCE !! :)

```css
   table, th, td {
    border: 3px solid #5c5f63;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    }
    th, td {
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
   
    }
    td{  
    word-wrap:break-word;
    color: red;
    background: #171819;
    }
    th{ 
    background: #000000;
    color: #00FF00;
    }
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 18px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #171819; 
 color: white;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    color: black;
    }
```

```html
   
    <body>
    <h2>Unchecked Loan Requests:</h2>

    <table style="width:80% " >
    <tr>
    <th>Loan ID:</th>
    <td>423</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Customer ID:</th>
    <td>1</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Customer Wanted Amount:</th>
    <td>4000</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Car Loan Type:</th>
    <td>new</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Duration (in years):</th>
    <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Annual Income:</th>
    <td>1980</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Licence:</th>
    <td>no</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Max Amount:</th>
    <td>20000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Years:</th>
    <td>1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>CC:</th>
    <td>1600cc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Loan Admin Amount Suggestion:</th>
    <td>17000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <th>Suggestion</th> 
    <td>wongweoginwgwegwgwegewgwegwegwegweg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Checked:</th>
    <td>no</td>   
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">DECISION</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Accept</a>
    <a href="#">Decline</a>
    <a href="#">Modify</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute of the `<select>` to call a JS function, which will redirect you to the servlet, adding the selected value as a parameter.

And I highly recommend you to go through some tutorials.